# Problem with ng class activate between two components

Tags: angular, events, output, angular-components, eventemitter

hello i would like to access the function onClick() in the app.component.ts through the submit-area.component.ts with Output() to control the ng class activate.

UseCase:

User clicks on Button Second and after he clicks on Submit he automatically gets to Button First.

Can you help me?

I created my code in StackBlitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lgzgn4

Answer (score 1):

I forked your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/problem-with-ng-class-activate) and made sure that button 2 is selected after clicking the submit button:

- add a click event on the submit button and emit your event emitter.
- in application.component.html bind the onClick event of the submit component to your submit function.

Answer (score 1):

child(submit component):html

```
<button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
```

child(submit component):ts here we will emit our event via @output to parent

```
@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      public submit() {
        this.valueChange.emit();
      }
```

and in parent html(button component) we will assign a function let say **display()** for event from child

```
<app-submit-area #component1 (valueChange)='display($event)' ></app-submit-area>
```

and handle display() function in your ts

```
display(){
/// your logic
 }
```

i have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6mmo3f) for you. hope this will solve your problem